# Python - JSON parsing using .ini options

Tags: python, json, configuration-files

Good localtime Python people,

I have a bunch of JSON responses I will be dealing with, with the following format:

```
    {
   "responseHeader":{
      "status":1,
      "params":{
         "indent":"true",
         "fq":"recordType:Vinyl",
         "wt":"json"
      }
   },
   "response":{
      "numFound":2,
      "albums":[
         {
            "name":"Some Crappy Album",
            "year":"1997",
            "artist":[
               "Bill's Polka Jamburri"
            ],
            "producer":[
               "Dope records"
            ],
         },
         {
            "name":"Best of Foreigner",
            "year":"2008",
            "artist":[
               "Foreginer"
            ],
            "producer":[
               "Rhino Entertainment"
            ],
         },
      ]
   }
}
```

And an .ini file that includes:

```
[Filters]
Exclude:somekey=somevalue
Include:somekey=somevalue
```

I already have code that uses urllib, urllib2, argparse and config parser that is capable of reading in a bunch of these records and doing stuff with data. **My question is, what would be the best way to implement filtering using my .ini file, where I could explicitly retrieve albums based on fields (Include:artist=devo) or exclude albums based on fields (Exclude:year=1979)?**

Below are my getOptionsFromConfigFile, loadJSON and getAlbums functions:

```
def getOptionsFromConfigFile( ):
    print "==========================================================================="
    print "Reading in config (.ini) file params ... "
    config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    config.read("config.ini")
    ExcludeParams = config.get("Filters", "Exclude")
    logging.debug(' Exclude params pulled from ini file: ' + JSONPath)
    IncludeParams = config.get("Filters", "Include")
    logging.debug(' Include params pulled from ini file: ' + JSONPath)
    return ExcludeParams, IncludeParams;

def loadJSON( ):
    print "Fetch Albums! ---> " + JSONPath
    print "==========================================================================="
    logging.debug('Loading ' + JSONPath)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(JSONPath)
    data = response.read()
    values = simplejson.loads(data)
    logging.debug('Dictionary pulled from ' + JSONPath)
    return values;

def getAlbums( values, outputPath):
    logging.debug('Getting Albums ...')
    for Album in values['response']['albums']:
        albumName = album['name']
        storeAlbum(outputPath)
    print "==========================================================================="
    return;
```

Comment: Are you asking how to use some python libraries to read the INI file?

Comment: No, I already have that done. I am asking the best way of implementing the filtration (Include and exclude) of the ini file. I could read each of those in, split on "=" and do something like: if values['somekey'] = somevalue then add album to list (for include) or if values['somekey']=somevalue then don't add album to list (for exclude). I can certainly throw together something that works, but I feel that there is a cleaner way to implement this.

Comment: I'm not seeing any ini related code in the question, can you [edit] to add it?

Comment: Just added that function

Comment: Note: Python doesn't need semicolon to return. Okay... How are you trying to use those functions together? The "best way" would be give parameters to the json methods, IMO

Comment: That's fine, and I expected that, I meant a little more detail on the filtration psuedocode though any syntax specific pointers/lib suggestions would be appreciated since I haven't touched Python in about 8 years, and was noob even then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can load `Exclude:year=1979` to a String, you would need to get a tuple, for example

```
('year', 1979)
```

Then, while you iterate the albums, you also need to iterate some list of exclusion or inclusion  tuples

```
# TODO: parse the exclusions and pass to this function 
def getAlbums( values, output_path, inclusions=None, exclusions=None):

    logging.debug('Getting Albums ...')

    albums = [] 
    for album in values['response']['albums']:
        for ex_key, ex_value in exclusions:
            # filter out the exclusions 
            if ex_key in album and album[ex_key] != ex_value:
                album_name = album['name']
                albums.append(album_name)

    for album in albums:
        store_album(album, output_path)
```

This approach isn't perfect, though, because what if you exclude and include overlapping values? Do you want add everything that isn't excluded or only the included values?

You might be better grabbing all the values in a list, then filtering afterwards

Comment: That works. Another problem with my current solution is that I am limited to including/excluding single key-value pairs. I could probably just add another split and create additional tuples.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used AND filters for each JSON element, "name", "year", "artist","producer" in my ini file, and created methods for each filter. Blank params are simply ignored. That ended up being significantly cleaner in the code, than my 9 layer nested include/exclude tuple implementation.